# convert django api to django-rest-framework api with 200 response code

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is my code which sends 200 api response after doing some stuffs.
It is working but, I wants to convert this as django-rest-framework way with DRF template.

```
  def refresh_dashboard(request):
      profile = request.session["profile"]
      refresh_profile_events(profile)
      # refresh_profile_events.apply_async(args=[profile])
      return JsonResponse({"code": 200, "msg": "success"})
```

Below code i am using  but it is giving below error.
Please have a look how we can achive this

```
  class RefreshAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
      permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

      def get_object(self):
          user = self.request.user
          return type('DashboardData', (), {"code": 200})()
```

Error:

```
      assert self.serializer_class is not None, (
        AssertionError: 'RefreshAPIView' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method.
```

Comment: Use [**`APIView`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) class

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the serializer concept there.

```
class RefreshAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = YourClass.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RefreshAPIViewSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

A seializer looks like this

```
class MoviesReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Movies
    fields = ['id', 'title', 'description', 'categories', 'tags']
```

I like to suggest you to read about ModelSerializer in Django-rest documentation, check the URL below.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer